# "LinkAssemblies" failed rebuilding the project as Xamarin explains

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to create an app from Android with Visual Studio. I followed the instruction on https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

Deploying an app was awful. Every two deploys I had to end VS with Task Manager and restart. For discovering an error I remarked a lot fo code, I fixed it and unremarked all code. Now I can't build my app because this error:

> The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'HandyApp.Code.LocationCore' (defined >in 'HandyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'HandyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could >not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve HandyApp.Code.LocationCore
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>     at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldReference reference)
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeFields(TypeDefinition type)
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
>     at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
>     at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
>     at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
>     at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
>     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()    HandyApp.Droid

I restarted everything, I deleted all bin and obj files, I made a coffee but it's still not working.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the linker property to none? It will increase the size of your app but should let you build until you can figure out what NuGet, other reference or target platform (you need to have a minimum of 4.0.3 for android) is giving you this problem.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what is your `LocationCore`, usually this error happens when your minimum Android target doesn't match the Apis/ Controls you used in your code.

Comment: `LocationCore` is my class. I resolved the problem to remove all settings. Now my question is: can I publish my app on the Google store without this settings?